Can you cite any evidence why this claim would be rejected
A method, comprising:
a. identifying at least one of a first score and a second score of a first user;
b. optionally, in response to identifying the first score, identifying a third score;
c. optionally, in response to identifying the second score, identifying a fourth score;
d. determining an output based on the first score, the second score, the third score, and the fourth score; and
e. sending the output to the first user,
wherein the method uses zero in place of scores that are not identified

questions:

Assuming that the method is novel, non-obvious, useful, and enabled in the specifications, can you cite any evidences, documents, rules, etc. to argue that this claim is invalid in some way because of the way it is written, phrased, worded, or constructed?
Actually, both steps (b) and (c) do in fact LIMIT the claim, because if they are identified, they will affect the output differently than if they are not identified. If they are not identified, then a zero is used in their place, which of course will have a different effect on an algorithm that uses it as input. So do you agree, that the optional step of (b) and (c) do in fact LIMIT the claim, and hence it is valid to have them?

PS:
In my option, this claim is clear enough in its English meaning that it should be understood by a high schooler. So as it relates to the English language, how can this claim be considered indefinite or ambiguous to someone skilled in the arts?
Note:
The details of each step, especially step (d), is obviously retracted to properly focus this question.

It is much improved from the example in your earlier questions. The optional language doesn’t bother me but b and c are not limiting. A system that never had a third or fourth score would still infringe.
It is awkward to require something in one step (d) that might not exist even though we later find out how to handle it.
I assume that the specification teaches what “identifying” means. From your other questions and comments it would seem more like “receiving” than identifying if is a user selection of a value.
As mentioned earlier this could also be written without the optional steps and those steps included in dependent claims instead.
The wording might cause less push back if d was

d. determining an output based on the identified scores;

That way you do not have a step explicitly requiring something that might not exist.

I wanted to write a comment but my score is too low.
In my opinion in steps b and c writing "optionally" renders those steps optional. That means even if you have a first score in step a, you don't necessarily need to identify a third score in step b, because step b is optional.
I would say b and c are limiting only if you remove the word "optionally".
Regarding your first question, without having made any search, I think your claim is very broad and you should be able to find prior art which reads into your claim.
